# Why does this show index out of range even tho all the index are valid?

Tags: python, list, indexoutofrangeexception

could someone please explain to me why this does not work, is there some underline issue I am not aware of when doing this?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
print(i)
print(a[i] + 3)

print(a)
a[i], a[a[i] + 3] = a[a[i] + 3], a[i] # this shows error even tho below is the same and does not
#a[0], a[4] = a[4], a[0]
print(a)
```

Comment: You are changing some array elements at confused timing.  Better to use: `j = a[i]+3;  a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]` if you want predictability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unpack doesn't all happen at the same time. It unpacks left to right.

Therefore when you unpack the tuple, you set `a[i] = a[a[i] + 3] = 5`, then you try to set `a[a[i] + 3] = a[i]`, but `a[i] + 3 = 8` which is out of range.

Comment: Needless to say, one should never write code like this for exactly this reason... If you want to prove this, `a[i], a[print(a[i]) or 0] = a[a[i] + 3], a[i]` will print 5.

Comment: I see, I was doing some problem wondering why the solution assigned the index to a variable so I tried to refactor and got this... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

after assigning `a[i]= a[a[i] + 3]` the list is now, `[5, 2, 3, 4, 5]` so, `a[a[i] + 3]` becomes `a[8]` which isn't there in the list.